# when i added code in collapsible-set.how to refresh collapsibleset in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a question. this is my html code:

```
 <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" id="set1" data-collapsed="false"  biaozhi="1">
            <legend>本周工作内容1</legend>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <textarea placeholder="请输入工作内容" style="height:60px;" name="text121" id="text121"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>完成情况:</legend>
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
                        <option value="0%">0%</option>
                        <option value="25%">25%</option>
                        <option value="50%">50%</option>
                        <option value="75%">75%</option>
                        <option value="100%" selected>100%</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a data-role="button" style="width:49%;" title="新增一行" data-icon="add" onclick="add_()">新增</a>
                <a data-role="button" style="width:49%;" title="删除一行" data-icon="delete" onclick="delete_()">删除</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i add a "collapsible" .then refresh collapsible-set.

```
var con = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" id="set1" data-collapsed="false"  biaozhi="1"><legend>本周工作内容1</legend><div data-role="fieldcontain"><textarea placeholder="请输入工作内容" style="height:60px;" name="text121" id="text121"></textarea></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>完成情况:</legend><select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1"><option value="0%">0%</option><option value="25%">25%</option><option value="50%">50%</option><option value="75%">75%</option><option value="100%" selected>100%</option></select></fieldset></div><div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><a data-role="button" style="width:49%;" title="新增一行" data-icon="add" onclick="add_()">新增</a><a data-role="button" style="width:49%;" title="删除一行" data-icon="delete" onclick="delete_()">删除</a></div></div>';


$("#set").append( con ).collapsibleset('refresh');
```

but i got a bad result:

the "collapsible" head has been refresh. but the collapsible's content dont refresh.

plz help me.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.trigger('create');` to re-enhance collapsible-set.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DUX7E/)**

```
$("#set").append( con ).collapsibleset().trigger('create');
```

Comment: wooot.You are so great、awesome。

Comment: i am sorry. i cant vote up. stackoverflow said: vote up requires 15 reputation.